# Azure Pipelines: Temporary folder to mount in docker container

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

I want to transfer test result from a docker container to build results and did it that way:

```
  steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          mkdir -p $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/reports
          chmod -f 777 $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/reports
      displayName: 'Prepare mount folder for reports'
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          docker run --rm -v $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/reports:/foo/reports $(image_tag) \
            /bin/bash -c 'pylint --output-format=pylint_junit.JUnitReporter:reports/pylint.xml,colorized  foo'
      displayName: 'Run pylint'
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      condition: always()
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
        testResultsFiles: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/reports/pylint.xml'
        failTaskOnFailedTests: false
```

Is `Build.SourcesDirectory` the correct place to use?

After cleaning up agents, I get permission errors. Instead of manually fixing them, I'd like to know if there is a better target folder for such tasks, e.g. `Build.StagingDirectory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably rely on the `Agent.TempDirectory`, which will automatically be cleaned up at the end of the job.

But the `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` is a great option too.

In both cases I'd probably create a subfolder underneath either one of the mentioned folders to copy the data in, should you then later want to create another artifact, you can just create another subfolder next to this one.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I also use a subfolder (`$(Agent.TempDirectory)/reports`).